# Why does addEventListener for load event not work with a div?

Tags: javascript

When adding an event listener for the `load` I can't just use a function literal like I do for the click event. Why can't I use a function literal like I do for my click event?

```
<body>
    <div>some content</div>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        // does not work (console is not written to when page loads)...
        div.addEventListener("load", function(){console.log("div load event")}, false);
        // works (console is written to when div content is clicked...
        div.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("div click event")}, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Divs don't fire `load` events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `load` event fires in elements which load external contents, such as `img`, `iframe`, etc.

The truth is `load` event may not fire case a content load before the event is declared. So, if you want the `load` event to work, you need to declare it before a `src` or `href`, for example.

Once the `div` is declared it's already loaded. So it's impossible to fire a event like this in the `div`.

If you want to know the `div`, including its elements such as `img` have loaded, you must declare the `load` event for each, i.e:

```
var loaded = 0;

var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    len = images.length;

function imgload() {
    if(++loaded > len) {
        console.log("Div loaded.");
    }
}

for(var i = 0, img; img = images[i]; i++) img.addEventListener("load", loaded);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add JS code for load event. Your load for div already finished. So load event will never be fired. And click works because it will appear later on when user click it. 
Read this to get better understanding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: He's code look OK...he just dont see difference for events fire in js. It was not to make him look bad. Just to make point that hey, look at this way. And try check this way. Sorry to hear that you think i try to insult him :-(.. But i will remove that statement. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem, context can be hard to judge from a written post

Comment: ;-) Glad to hear. Hope that response helps OP.